# Power BI Counting proper time between dates of order?

Tags: time, powerbi, dax, orders

I have some problems with my Power BI formulas and i dont know how to obtain the proper result. I will show you my file below.

I would like to get a result (proper time) between every step in this order. So example count time from the end of order (index1 = 4) and step (index1 = 3), then step (index1  = 3) and step (index 1 =  2)for the same order (support column have to be the same ex. 9). I tried but results are'n enough accurate.

My formulas:
`Days = MAX(0,CALCULATE(MIN(Orders[Data]),FILTER(Orders,Orders[Supporting Column]=EARLIER(Orders[Supporting Column])&&Orders[index1]>EARLIER(Orders[index1])))-Orders[Data])`

`Seconds = Orders[Days]*24*60*60`

```
Supporting Column = 
CALCULATE (
    MIN ( Orders[index] ),
    ALLEXCEPT ( Orders, Orders[Order Number])
)
```

```
index1 = 
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        Orders,
        EARLIER ( Orders[Order Number]) = Orders[Order Number]
    ),
    Orders[Data],
    ,
    ASC
)
```

```
index = RANKX(ALL(Orders[Unique(order + date)]),Orders[Unique(order + date)],,ASC)
```

Power BI image:
[image: Power BI image]

Power BI sample of data:
[Power BI sample of data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pQgKRB5pcG97Wx6PP_bIBzwGmbv2mZ4YWuFClQG40sU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: What is your expected output? I don't fully understand what you are after.

Comment: My expected output is last column (Time between stages) but need proper calculate. In this case i have 3 orders. For each of them different tasks (marked with the same number in "supporting column"). First order has 5 tasks (number 9 in "supporting column") with diff time. I created column "index1" to sort this tasks form the earliest to the lastest from 1-5. And now i want to calculate the diff between "data" for "index1"=5 and "inedex1"=4, then "index1"=4 and "index1"=3 and so on.